# Backand user object not associated with custom user object if created through API

Tags: backand

I have created a custom "users" object that I know is associated with backand's user object. However when I created them from my app using Backand's SDK, I can see the user being created in the Backand's registered users but not in my custom object "users"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a permissions issue. Not documented well either. If your Anonymous Access is set to (read only) and you remove the try catch statement from the "Create My App User" server side javascript you will get a 401 error in your client. Set Anonymous Access to public and it works first try. There is probably a better way to do this but I am still looking into it I dont want to give the Anonymous Users that much access. But it definitely proved it is permissions issue.

Comment: This did the trick - Updated the anonymous access to "user"... Thanks Eric!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the following security actions in Security & Auth and that their conditions is set to true:
Event - During create,
Name - Create My App User
Code:

```
/* globals
$http - Service for AJAX calls 
CONSTS - CONSTS.apiUrl for Backands API URL
Config - Global Configuration
*/
'use strict';
function backandCallback(userInput, dbRow, parameters, userProfile) {

   // When a new user registers, add her to the users object. 
   // If you are using a different object for your users then change this action accordingly. 
   if (parameters.sync)
      return {};
   if (!parameters)
      parameters = {};
   parameters.email = userInput.Username;
   parameters.firstName = userInput.FirstName;
   parameters.lastName = userInput.LastName;
   try{
   var response = $http({
      method: "POST",
      url:CONSTS.apiUrl + "/1/objects/users",
      params: {parameters: {"sync": true}},
      data: parameters,
      headers: {"Authorization": userProfile.token}
   });
}
catch(err) {
   // register user even if there is an error or no users object 
}
   return {};
}
```

Event - During update,
Name - Update My App User
Code:

```
/* globals
$http - Service for AJAX calls 
CONSTS - CONSTS.apiUrl for Backands API URL
Config - Global Configuration
*/
'use strict';
function backandCallback(userInput, dbRow, parameters, userProfile) {

   // When a registered user is changed, change your users object as well. 
   // If you are using a different object for your users then change this action accordingly. 

   // Get the user id by the user's email
   var currentUser = $http({
      method: "GET",
      url:CONSTS.apiUrl + "/1/objects/users",
      params: {filter:[{"fieldName":"email", "operator":"equals", "value": userInput.Username }]},
      headers: {"Authorization": userProfile.token}
   });
   if (currentUser.data.length == 1) { 
      var currentUserId = currentUser.data[0].__metadata.id; 
      var response = $http({
         method: "PUT",
         url:CONSTS.apiUrl + "/1/objects/users/" + currentUserId + "",
         params: {},
         data: {"firstName": userInput.FirstName, "lastName": userInput.LastName },
         headers: {"Authorization": userProfile.token}
      });
   } 

   return {};
}
```

Event - During delete,
Name - Delete My App User
Code:

```
/* globals
$http - Service for AJAX calls 
CONSTS - CONSTS.apiUrl for Backands API URL
Config - Global Configuration
*/
'use strict';
function backandCallback(userInput, dbRow, parameters, userProfile) {

   // When a registered user name is deleted, delete her from your users object as well. 
   // If you are using a different object for your users then change this action accordingly. 

   // Get the user id by the user's email
   var currentUser = $http({
      method: "GET",
      url:CONSTS.apiUrl + "/1/objects/users",
      params: {filter:[{"fieldName":"email", "operator":"equals", "value": dbRow.Username }]},
      headers: {"Authorization": userProfile.token}
   });
   if (currentUser.data.length == 1) { 
      var currentUserId = currentUser.data[0].__metadata.id; 
      var response = $http({
         method: "DELETE",
         url:CONSTS.apiUrl + "/1/objects/users/" + currentUserId + "",
         params: {},
         headers: {"Authorization": userProfile.token}
      });
   } 

   return {};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I checked and all the security actions are the default ones and what you have mentioned above (name, condition, trigger event, etc.)
Also, in the security actions, you can test a action on the right, with that i see an object being created in both the backand's user object as well as the custom object that I created. Any thoughts, why it is failing via a web service call?

Comment: Here is code that calls the webservice from my app
$scope.signup = function (user, signUpToken) {
      return $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url : Backand.getApiUrl() + '/1/user/signup',
          headers: {
            SignUpToken: Signtoken
          },
          data: {
  firstName: user.firstName,
  lastName: user.lastName,
  email: user.email,
  password: user.password,
  confirmPassword: user.password,
  
}
      })